# Offset addressing

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, debugging, binary-analysis

I’m writing a C-SKY (CK803S) processor module for IDA Pro, and a question arose about offsets in transitions, small ones are fine, but long ones lead to nowhere, from the documentation:
[image]

in code I implemented it like this:`insn.Op1.addr = insn.ea + (((code32 & 0x3FFFFFF) << 1) & 0x3FFFFFF);`

[image]

but I don’t understand what sign_extend does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signextend is expanding an integer of some size into a larger size and filling the extra bits with the original sign bit. In other words - keeping the larger int positive/negative.

Example:

An original 8-bit number `0x7F` (Binary `01111111`) signextended to 32 bit becomes `0x0000007F`.

An original 8-bit number `0x80` (Binary `10000000`) signextended to 32 bit becomes `0xFFFFFF80`

It makes sense using this operation in offsets as a relative offset can be negative.

Comment: that is, if 26 bits are 0, then we set bits 31..26 to 0, otherwise to 1? or force set to 1 - sign_extend, to 0 - zero_extend?

Comment: If the most significant bit is 1 - all additional higher bits are set to 1. Otherwise - 0. signed, `(int8) 0xFF` equals to decimal`-1`. To keep the value in 32 bit they have to be all 1s, i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`